# We updated our PHP from 7.2 to 7.4 and are now getting an "Internal Servor Error" when someone uses our Request a Quote form. Please help!

Tags: craft2

We updated our PHP from 7.2 to 7.4 and are now getting an "Internal Servor Error" when someone uses our Request a Quote form. Please help!
[image]

We use Hubspot to send the leads to our email if that's important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something in your Craft build is not compatible with PHP 7.4.

Craft core became PHP 7.4 compatible in v. 2.8.0, so make sure you're on at least that version – ideally, you should update to the latest version (2.9.2).

If the error still occurs on Craft 2.8+, the culprit is going to be a plugin. To find the cuplrit, you'll need to check your logs (either `craft.log` or `phperrors.log` in the `craft/storage/runtime/logs` directory, should have some additional info and hopefully a stack trace). Alternatively, you can (temporarily!) enable [`devMode`](https://craftcms.com/docs/2.x/config-settings.html#devmode), which should give you a full in-browser stack trace when the error occurs.

If/when you find the offending plugin, you'll need to hunt down an updated version for it that is PHP 7.4 compatible. If an updated version doesn't exist, you'll either need to fix the compatibility issue yourself, or downgrade PHP to the oldest compatible version.

In any case, you should probably consider upgrading your site to Craft 3 or 4 as soon as possible, considering Craft 2 has been EOL since January 2022.